# Need to Check a Span of days for Reservation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a reservation system for an Exotic Pet Boarding Hotel. I have the basics for checking the reservation limit with the check-in date but I need to check all dates till the check-out date.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReservationId,Location,ReservationDate,OwnerAssetId,CheckOutDate")] Reservation reservation)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var loc = db.Locations.Where(x => x.LocationId == reservation.Location1.LocationId).FirstOrDefault(); //current location
            byte limit = loc.ReservationLimit; //limit for the place

            var dayDate = db.Reservations.Where(x => x.ReservationDate == reservation.ReservationDate && x.Location1.LocationId == reservation.Location1.LocationId).Count();

            if (limit < dayDate)
            {
                db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["LimitReached"] = "There are no open spots for that time frame.";
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }


        }

        ViewBag.Location = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationId", "LocationName", reservation.Location);
        ViewBag.OwnerAssetId = new SelectList(db.OwnerAssets, "OwnerAssetId", "AssetName", reservation.OwnerAssetId);
        return View(reservation);
    }
```

[Code From Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAp9L.png)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "html" and the tag should be removed.  (It's not really about databases, either, for that matter.)  Further there is insufficient information here to answer the question.  Provide more details, or better yet, a minimal runnable example.

Comment: So, it sounds like what you want to do is find out if there are any days, between the new reservation's date and its checkout date, where the count of reservations on that day is less than the location's limit, minus 1 (to allow for the new reservation).

Comment: What I'd do is get all the reservations between those two dates, group them by day, and get a list of each day and its reservation count. Then check to see if any of those counts are greater than the location's limit - 1. This should be doable in LINQ; Just do a search for "c# linq groupby date count".